# How filter nested array of objects by date

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
const data =  [
  {
    id: '3499934913',
    user_data: {
      user_data_stays: [
        {
          value: '30.0',
          date: '2021-10-01T12:55:00.000Z',
        },
        {
          value: '30.0',
          date: '2021-11-01T12:55:00.000Z',
        },
        {
          value: '30.0',
          date: '2021-13-01T12:55:00.000Z',
        }
      ],
    }
  },
  {
    id: '43534535',
    user_data: {
      user_data_stays: [
        {
          value: '30.0',
          date: '2021-11-01T12:55:00.000Z',
        },
        {
          value: '30.0',
          date: '2021-12-01T12:55:00.000Z',
        },
        {
          value: '30.0',
          date: '2021-13-01T12:55:00.000Z',
        }
      ],
    }
  },
]
```

How can I keep the structure of the whole array but filter in `user_data_stays` only those objects which date is equal to `2021-10-01T12:55:00.000Z`?

I tried using filter and some but I am not able to get to the nested element inside.
I think the problem is the amount of nesting, and I can't deal with that. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use forEach on the outer array and run filter method on inner array with the help of de-structuring, the object reference will update the outer object in-place.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "3499934913",
    user_data: {
      user_data_stays: [
        { value: "30.0", date: "2021-10-01T12:55:00.000Z" },
        { value: "30.0", date: "2021-11-01T12:55:00.000Z" },
        { value: "30.0", date: "2021-13-01T12:55:00.000Z" },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    id: "43534535",
    user_data: {
      user_data_stays: [
        { value: "30.0", date: "2021-11-01T12:55:00.000Z" },
        { value: "30.0", date: "2021-12-01T12:55:00.000Z" },
        { value: "30.0", date: "2021-13-01T12:55:00.000Z" },
      ],
    },
  },
];


data.forEach(({ user_data }) => {
  user_data.user_data_stays = user_data.user_data_stays
    .filter(({ date }) => date === '2021-10-01T12:55:00.000Z');
});

console.log(data);
```